# How to access directive's controller $scope properties inside controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have to access value from directive's controller inside my controller.

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
      <my-directive atr="xyz"></my-directive>
    </div>
```

//here is my directive

```
app.directive('myDirective',function() {
return {
 restrict : 'E',
 replace : false,
 scope :{
 atr :'@'
},
 controller : function($scope) {
  console.log($scope.atr); //xyz
 $scope.keyPoint ="this is what i want to access inside myCtrl";
 }
}

});
```

//here is ctrl

```
app.controller('myCtrl',function($scope){
//how can I access keyPoint here
})
```

Answer (score 1):

**Isolating scope:**

**You Should use `two-way` binding for the keypoint to achieve this.**

```
scope :{
    atr :'@',
    keyPoint: '='
    },
```

What this will do is **when ever you change the value in Directive, it reflects in your Controller**, and vice-versa

```js
// Instantiate the app, the 'myApp' parameter must 
// match what is in ng-app
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

// Create the controller, the 'ToddlerCtrl' parameter 
// must match an ng-controller directive
myApp.directive('myDirective',function() {
    return {
        restrict : 'E',
        replace : false,
        scope :{
        atr :'@',
        keyPoint: '='
        },
        controller : function($scope) {
        console.log($scope.atr); //xyz
        $scope.keyPoint ="this is what i want to access inside myCtrl";
        }
    }

});

myApp.controller('myCtrl',function($scope,$timeout){
  $timeout(function(){
    alert($scope.keypoint)
   },500)
   
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.7" data-semver="1.2.7" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.7/angular.js"></script>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Starter AngularJS app</h1>
       <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
          <my-directive atr="xyz" key-point="keypoint"></my-directive>
      </div>
    {{keypoint}}
  </body>

</html>
```

**Please run this snippet**

[Here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/11007/)

**Without Isolating scope:**

If you want to get the scope of the controller in the directive, dont     Isolate the scope in the directive.
If you Isolate the scope, you cannot get controller's scope.

```js
// Instantiate the app, the 'myApp' parameter must 
// match what is in ng-app
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

// Create the controller, the 'ToddlerCtrl' parameter 
// must match an ng-controller directive
myApp.directive('myDirective',function() {
    return {
        restrict : 'E',
        replace : false,
        controller : function($scope) {
        console.log($scope.atr); //xyz
        $scope.keyPoint ="this is what i want to access inside myCtrl";
        }
    }

});

myApp.controller('myCtrl',function($scope,$timeout){
  $scope.atr="xyz"
  $timeout(function(){
 alert($scope.keyPoint)
    $scope.$apply();
},500)
   
})
```

```html
<script data-require="angular.js@1.2.7" data-semver="1.2.7" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.7/angular.js"></script>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  <body  ng-app="myApp">
    <h1>Starter AngularJS app</h1>
       <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
          <my-directive ></my-directive>
         <h1>{{keyPoint}}</h1>
      </div>
    
  </body>
```

[Fiddle for second snippet](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/11012/)

Comment: @unknown, Please run the snippet and check.

Comment: i dont want to pass key point as a attibute. i just want to use keypoint inside my main controller.

Comment: in my directive's controller i am getting object as rest call response.so i want to use that object inside my main controller.

Comment: just remove the scope in directive

Comment: check the second snippet.

Comment: i removed scope from directive.its getting populated in html(as i use {{}}])

Comment: but inside controller i am getting undefined

Comment: If you want to get the scope of the controller in the directive, dont Isolate the scope in the directive.
If you Isolate the scope, you cannot get controller's scope.

Comment: @unknown, Please run the snippet now.

Comment: use bindToController in 1.3+.  refer to [this](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angularjs/2015/01/02/exploring-angular-1.3-bindToController.html) and [this](https://toddmotto.com/no-scope-soup-bind-to-controller-angularjs/).  Working plnkr [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/6grAXKeZutCuSp9AxP2n?p=preview)

Comment: @Sravan accrding to your last snippet. atr is undefine inside directive's controller. i want to acess atr also

Comment: actually i made directive to upload file to server using FileTransfer object(cordova),

Comment: <fil-upload destination="som/pat/to/server"><file-upload>

Comment: every modal you change will be available in directive,  `ng-model`, every input tag change will be availbale to directive using scope, even the file field.

Comment: after uploading I need the response object inside my main controller ho can i achive this??

Comment: just assign that response in directive scope, then automatically controller scope gets refreshed.

Comment: for example,  `$scope.keyPoint`  is assigned in directive and the response is printed in your controller, same as that.

Comment: But why i need key-point to set as attribute in directive?? ex: <my-directive atr ="sdfs" key-point="Why this is required??">

Comment: there is no attribute in the directive, check the second snippet

Comment: can you please create directive that shoud accept on attribute.as <file-upload url="path/to/server"><file-upload>

Comment: what I did,  <file-upload url="path/to/server"><file-upload> ,

Comment: my Main controller: app.controller('mainCtrl',function(){})

Comment: inside main ctrl there is a method as $scope.submitForm = function() {//here i need some file id that i will get from response of file upload api }

Comment: and file upload function is written inside directive's controller function

Comment: ok, when you upload the file, you are adding something to scope in the directive?